# Conditionally loaded data in API resource: How to "pass" a condition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-api, laravel-resource

I got a little issue to solve. In my app I am handling with a lot of Models and each model does have something like:

- ModelResource
- ModelResourceCollection
- ModelResourceOverview
- ModelResourceOverviewCollection

The reason is: Sometimes I don't need all the information that are visible if I am using the `ModelResource` - in this case I am calling the `ModelResourceOverview`.

### Example

**PostResource**

```
- title
- tags
- content
- author
```

### Example

**PostOverviewResource**

```
- title
- author
```

As I have a lot of Models I have a huge number of ApiResource-Classes and I want to get rid of that.

I thought about using `$this->when` in the Resource and pass something like "full" or "overview" to the request in the Controller.

### Example

```
$data
    = new PostResource($this->post);
```

So my question is: Is it the best way to add this to the `request` or is there a handier/nicer way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a way to hide fields on the fly: [Hiding attributes from json](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

e.g.

```
return $post->makeHidden('content')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your logic about "visible or not" is bound to the current request, then you should use `when` or `mergeWhen` as you mentioned (everything here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes ), therefore you'll only have 2 resources instead of 4

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'author' => $this->author,
        $this->mergeWhen($this->needsFullData($request), [
            'tags' => $this->tags,
            'content' => $this->content,
        ]),
    ];
}

protected function needsFullData($request)
{
    //Your logic
}
```